# Convert Func<T,bool> to String

Tags: string, lambda, type-conversion

I'm needing to convert a Func expression into the string equivalent. For example, if I have this expression:

`Customers.Where(c => c.State == "AZ")`

I need to be able to convert the expression in the where method to:

`"c => c.State == 'AZ'"`

I need to convert the expression in the lambda to the raw text equivalent.